# How do I disconnect from my EC2 Instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I would have thought this would be a question I could find the answer to with a quick Google search, but I can't. I have connected to my EC2 instance via an SSH client but now I would like to disconnect, but I have no idea how.

Comment: Type exit and key enter

Comment: @Doleron thank you. I wondered if that was it but was too scared to mess anything up.

Comment: No problem. The way to go is asking always you are in doubt.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Simply typing the `exit` command will log you out of your instance.

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 19):

There are a number of ways you can end your SSH session.

Simply closing the client should be sufficient.

You can type `exit` or `logout` to explicitly end your session.

Another approach is to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> which will send an `EOF` to the shell and terminate your session.